# How to tell which service or task caused a certain 4624 logon event?

Tags: windows, login, services, scheduled-tasks, event-viewer

I found a series of Windows logon events 4624 like this:

```
An account was successfully logged on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       mycomputername$
    Account Domain:     WORKGROUP
    Logon ID:       0x3E7

Logon Information:
    Logon Type:     5
    Restricted Admin Mode:  -
    Virtual Account:        No
    Elevated Token:     Yes

Impersonation Level:        Impersonation

New Logon:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       SYSTEM
    Account Domain:     NT AUTHORITY
    Logon ID:       0x3E7
    Linked Logon ID:        0x0
    Network Account Name:   -
    Network Account Domain: -
    Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x3cc
    Process Name:       C:\Windows\System32\services.exe

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   -
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      Advapi  
    Authentication Package: Negotiate
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0
```

Each of them is followed by another 4672 event

```
Special privileges assigned to new logon.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       SYSTEM
    Account Domain:     NT AUTHORITY
    Logon ID:       0x3E7

Privileges:     SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege
            SeTcbPrivilege
            SeSecurityPrivilege
            SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege
            SeLoadDriverPrivilege
            SeBackupPrivilege
            SeRestorePrivilege
            SeDebugPrivilege
            SeAuditPrivilege
            SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege
            SeImpersonatePrivilege
            SeDelegateSessionUserImpersonatePrivilege
```

From the looks of this, it seems that certain service or scheduled task is causing these logons. I tried to look into `Windows Logs\Application` and `Windows Logs\System` but found no event that happened at the same time of these logons. I am confused as to how to locate the service or task that is causing these logons. Any suggestions or hints are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The first event is documented by Microsoft in the article
[4624(S): An account was successfully logged on](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4624).

The Logon Type is `5`, which means
"A service was started by the Service Control Manager".
As recorded, the event was generated by `C:\Windows\System32\services.exe` which
is the Services Control Manager, that is responsible for running, ending,
and interacting with system services.

The subject system service is started with the SYSTEM account, which gives it
basically unlimited powers, which causes the issuing of
[4672(S): Special privileges assigned to new logon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4672).

The logon process is marked as "advapi", which could mean that
the logon was a Web-based logon through the IIS web server and
the `advapi` process. However, this is so only for Logon Type 3
which is a network source. Yours is type 5, which is internal
to the computer.

Your computer is probably not infected.

Reference
[Chapter 5 Logon/Logoff Events](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/book/page.aspx?spid=chapter5).

---

More information :

This event is described in the article
[4624(S): An account was successfully logged on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4624).
It is logged for any type of logon.

You can see the provenance of the event from the `LogonType` field:

| Logon Type | Logon Title | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | System | Used only by the System account, for example at system startup. |
| 2 | Interactive | A user logged on to this computer. |
| 3 | Network | A user or computer logged on to this computer from the network. |
| 4 | Batch | Batch logon type is used by batch servers, where processes may be executing on behalf of a user without their direct intervention. |
| 5 | Service | A service was started by the Service Control Manager. |
| 7 | Unlock | This workstation was unlocked. |
| 8 | NetworkCleartext | A user logged on to this computer from the network. The user's password was passed to the authentication package in its unhashed form. The built-in authentication packages all hash credentials before sending them across the network. The credentials do not traverse the network in plaintext (also called cleartext). |
| 9 | NewCredentials | A caller cloned its current token and specified new credentials for outbound connections. The new logon session has the same local identity, but uses different credentials for other network connections. |
| 10 | RemoteInteractive | A user logged on to this computer remotely using Terminal Services or Remote Desktop. |
| 11 | CachedInteractive | A user logged on to this computer with network credentials that were stored locally on the computer. The domain controller was not contacted to verify the credentials. |
| 12 | CachedRemoteInteractive | Same as RemoteInteractive. This is used for internal auditing. |
| 13 | CachedUnlock | Workstation logon. |

Comment: I think it my case it ended up being SSRS which doesn't directly use IIS but has similar OS/http.sys ties.

Comment: It was stated that `The logon process is marked as "advapi", which means that the logon was a Web-based logon through the IIS web server and the advapi process.` Presumably, this knowledge was derived from [a Ultimate Windows Security section](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/book/page.aspx?spid=chapter5). In that link, we see that the above fact was indeed mentioned. However, the context was that it was event ID 4624 with **logon type 3**. The original post was about **logon type 5**.

Comment: @BrianLee: I missed out on your comment in 2022. Corrected in 2023.