# Is an Advapi Logon Process (Event 4624) Always Related to a Web-Based Logon Via an IIS Server?

Tags: windows, windows-10, login

I know searching through Event Viewer can be pointless, but I'm seeing a lot of these logons and don't have an IIS server.

They're exactly as posted here [How to tell which service or task caused a certain 4624 logon event?](https://superuser.com/questions/1574474/how-to-tell-which-service-or-task-caused-a-certain-4624-logon-event) by another user.

The answer indicated that the computer could be compromised but I don't think that's the case. However, being that I don't have an IIS server, I can't understand these logons and they're consistent.

Can someone with more knowledge kindly advise as to what these are if not related to a web-based logon/IIS server?

The rest of the event viewer general tab:
An account was successfully logged on.

```
Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       [HOSTNAME]$
    Account Domain:     WORKGROUP
    Logon ID:       0x3E7

Logon Information:
    Logon Type:     5
    Restricted Admin Mode:  -
    Virtual Account:        No
    Elevated Token:     Yes

Impersonation Level:        Impersonation

New Logon:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       SYSTEM
    Account Domain:     NT AUTHORITY
    Logon ID:       0x3E7
    Linked Logon ID:        0x0
    Network Account Name:   -
    Network Account Domain: -
    Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x3b8
    Process Name:       C:\Windows\System32\services.exe

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   -
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      Advapi  
    Authentication Package: Negotiate
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0
```

Answer (score 0):

This event does not mean that your computer is compromised.

This event is described in the article
[4624(S): An account was successfully logged on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4624).
It is logged for any type of logon, not only for web.

You can see the provenance of the event from the `LogonType` field:

| Logon Type | Logon Title | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | System | Used only by the System account, for example at system startup. |
| 2 | Interactive | A user logged on to this computer. |
| 3 | Network | A user or computer logged on to this computer from the network. |
| 4 | Batch | Batch logon type is used by batch servers, where processes may be executing on behalf of a user without their direct intervention. |
| 5 | Service | A service was started by the Service Control Manager. |
| 7 | Unlock | This workstation was unlocked. |
| 8 | NetworkCleartext | A user logged on to this computer from the network. The user's password was passed to the authentication package in its unhashed form. The built-in authentication packages all hash credentials before sending them across the network. The credentials do not traverse the network in plaintext (also called cleartext). |
| 9 | NewCredentials | A caller cloned its current token and specified new credentials for outbound connections. The new logon session has the same local identity, but uses different credentials for other network connections. |
| 10 | RemoteInteractive | A user logged on to this computer remotely using Terminal Services or Remote Desktop. |
| 11 | CachedInteractive | A user logged on to this computer with network credentials that were stored locally on the computer. The domain controller was not contacted to verify the credentials. |
| 12 | CachedRemoteInteractive | Same as RemoteInteractive. This is used for internal auditing. |
| 13 | CachedUnlock | Workstation logon. |

Your logon event comes from an internal Windows service,
not instigated by any external source.

Comment: thanks so much for the reply!  I added the remainder of the contents of the general tab pertaining to the event to the original post.  Does this help narrow it down?  I just changed the actual account name to [hostname]$...as I understand it, that's the system's username.  Any further thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: "Logon Type: 5" means "A service was started by the Service Control Manager". It means that a system service running under a local account has started (`services.exe`). It's not related at all to the web. Your case is very different from that link you gave to a post which I have also answered in the past. This event is internal to your computer and looks pretty normal.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).

Comment: thanks again for the insightful response which was helpful!  How is this logon very different, though, from the one in the link I gave?  I looked at both and they look nearly identical.

Comment: That answer was mine too, and the logon type was different.

Comment: I appreciate all your help but the logon type wasn't different...there were both type 5.  Same security ID, Login ID, etc.  I'm trying to understand why that one was bookmarked as potentially malicious but these logins on my PC aren't.  What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing the fact that the previous answer was not precise, as the `Advapi` source was only dangerous in the case of Logon Type 3. Type 5 is internal to the machine, while type 3 is external. I'll need to fix that answer from 3 years ago, so thank you for putting up this post before the other one worried someone else.

Comment: The other answer is now fixed.